# Remove specific menu item from Wordpress admin menu for a specific role

Tags: wordpress, roles

I need to remove the Premmerce plugin menu item from the admin menu (leaving it visible only to the admin and hidden for all other roles).

I had the same problem with the JetPack menu item which I fixed by adding this code to the functions.php file:

```
function ap_remove_jetpack_page( ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ap_remove_jetpack_page', 999 );
```

I would like to do the same for the Premmerce menu item. How can I do?

Thankyou

Comment: There are many Premmerce plugins. Which one you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the main `premmerce` plugin then you can use following code.

```
function remove_premmerce_menu_item() {
    // Check if Premmerce plugin is active
    if ( is_plugin_active( 'premmerce/premmerce.php' ) && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'premmerce' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_premmerce_menu_item', 999 );
```

Comment: It does not work :/
Look here: https://ibb.co/XYNbpmt

Comment: I updated the code. check now.

Comment: It still does not work :(
I don't know if it's important but the plugin is deactivated for this user role, only the menu item appears.

Comment: How did you deactivate the plugin for this user role?

Comment: Using the 'User Role Editor' plugin, I assigned only the management of registered users to this role.
In fact, if I click on the Premmerce menu item, the message appears: "You do not have permission to access this page."

Comment: The code you entered doesn't work, look here: https://ibb.co/rx4spKh

Comment: Looks like it required further debugging.

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't understand

Comment: I mean it required further debugging in your site.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to check this statement

```
 class_exists( 'Jetpack' )
```

`current_user_can` is enough.

What you need is to know the slug this can be done by following those steps from the extension search page

1. Click on `more details`
   [image]
2. Click on `Wordpress.org extension page`
   [image]
3. The slug is in the URL
   [image]

You can test with other plugins to verify if the behaviour is still correct.

Sources

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103917/removing-the-main-link-to-jetpack-from-the-menu
- https://wpsimplehacks.com/how-to-remove-wordpress-admin-menu-items/
- https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/ List of plugin slugs

Comment: The JetPack menu item is properly hidden, the problem is with the "Premmerce" menu item, look here: https://ibb.co/rx4spKh